# Deleting a property from a clone deletes it from the original as well. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an object that contains data I read from a file (called it data).
I cloned a property from it (called images) to another object (called tempixy ) and deleted a property (called src) from each element within the clone,
but for some reason the property got deleted from the original object as well.
I tried cloning the object with `Object.assign({}, data.images)` as well but it still wont work.
I know can access the event directly but I prefer not to.

```
function openFile(evt) {

      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
      fileReader.onload = e => {
        let data=JSON.parse(e.target.result)
        let tempixy ={...data.images};
        Object.keys(tempixy).map(function (key, index) {
          delete tempixy[key].src
        });
        console.log(data.images) //->prints it without the src property
        
      };
     
      evt.target.value = null;
  }
```

Comment: You’re not deleting the property from the cloned data, you’re deleting it from an object within the cloned data. You’re not doing a deep clone so the objects are the same in both.

Comment: I wonder if it may be related to the spread operator `...` performing a shallow-copy - please [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator (`...`) will perform a **shallow** clone, e.g. supose you're trying to do

```js
const obj = {
  some: 'property',
  another: {
    deep: 'property',
  },
};

const clone = { ...obj };
```

The spread operator will take the keys `some` and `another` and will put them with their respective values into the new object. Notice the `deep` key **will not** be cloned, so if you change `clone.another.deep`, this will reflect to `obj.another.deep`.

What you'd have to do then is

```js
const deepClone = {
  ...obj,
  another: {
    ...obj.another
  },
};
```

And repeat it for all levels of nesting your object have, which is an obnoxious task though. Luckily, there's the `cloneDeep` method from lodash which does exactly this.

```js
import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep';

const deepClone = cloneDeep(obj);
```

Comment: Wow, didnt even think it works that way. It works for me now, thx